# How to access and modify quick parts in msword using java program?

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to access and modify the quick parts values in my .doc file using java program. I am using the Apache POI library for this. All quick parts are in a table but when i am trying to read table contents, all text values other than quick parts are displayed. The  quick part cell is almost skipped. Can anyone suggest me an idea for doing this?

Thanks,
uday